# Flash Builder Error Compiling Ipad Actionscript Mobile Project

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, mobile, air, flash-builder

I just bought a brand new ipad for testing. I am using flash buider 4.7 to make an actionscript mobile project. I created an app ID, provisioning profile, and certificate. I have done this before in flash professional so it wasn't too bad. However, when I run or debug  even a blank application I get this error in flash builder:

Error occurred while packaging the application:

```
'Launching AppName' has encountered a problem.

Error occurred while packaging the application. 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unable to find llvm JNI lib in:
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/lib/adt.jar/Darwin
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/lib/aot/lib/x64
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/lib/adt.jar
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/lib

    at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.loadJNI(LLVMEmitter.java:582)
    at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.<clinit>(LLVMEmitter.java:596)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.generateExtensionsGlue(AOTCompiler.java:419)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.generateMachineBinaries(AOTCompiler.java:1790)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.createIosBinary(IPAOutputStream.java:378)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.finalizeSig(IPAOutputStream.java:762)
    at com.adobe.air.ApplicationPackager.createPackage(ApplicationPackager.java:91)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAPackager.createPackage(IPAPackager.java:245)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:571)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:419)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:469)
```

I have no idea where to even start in trying to figure out what could be the problem. I am pretty sure the itunes developer information is correct. Are there any kinds of drivers or developer modes that I need to set for a new iPad?
Thanks!

Comment: you shouldnt need anything else. are you trying to launch on ipad or in simulator?

Comment: Hey, it works now. I had to reinstall the air sdk. To do that I followed the steps here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html